# Sequence in which products are added is not maintained

Tags: java, collections

I have a webstore that allows the user to add products into the cart and do a checkout.

The problem is that whenever I add multiple products into the cart and display them on the cart page the sequence in which they are added is inconsistent with the display. In short, the products that were added last end up getting displayed on top instead of in the last spot.

I am using HashMap to add products into the cart and then iterate over them while displaying the values on the cart page.

Here the first arguments in the HashMap is ProductID which is String and the second argument is the Product object itself.

Am I using the correct Collection class i.e. HashMap for storing values or is there any other collection  object which could solve this inconsistent display issue that I am facing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) to preserve order